# Jquery else if statements not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, input

I am facing a problem while using else if statement in jquery, the function fires up when the input text in a table gets changed. In the table, there are two value range Normal and Critical, based on the values the colors of the input text background is supposed to change. The conditions fail to work on one instance.

```
    $("#myTable input").change(function () {
        var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
        var col4 = currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").html();
        var col5 = currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").html();

        var n_range = col4.split("-");
        var c_range = col5.split("-");

        inp = $(this).val();
        // alert(inp);

        if (inp > n_range[0] && inp < n_range[1]) {
            //if inp falls in the normal range color white
            $(this).css("background-color", "#FFF");
            $(this).css("color", "#37474F");
        } else if (inp > c_range[0] && inp < c_range[1]) {
            //if inp falls in the criticl range color red
            $(this).css("background-color", "#FF1744");
            $(this).css("color", "#FFF");
        } else if (inp < n_range[0]) {
            //if inp is higher than noraml range color  lightred
            $(this).css("background-color", "#FFF176");
            $(this).css("color", "#263238");
        } else if (inp < c_range[0]) {
            //not working
            $(this).css("background-color", "#E53935");
            $(this).css("color", "#FF5252");
            alert(n_range[1]);
        } else {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#2196F3");
            $(this).css("color", "#FFF");
        }
    });
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NEIc.png)

If the input text value falls in between the normal range then the background-color will turn white (#FFF).

If the input text value is less than normal values then the background color will turn yellow.

If the values falls in between the critical range the color will turn red.

All these works fine, but when the input text value is higher than normal values then the background color should turn light red but when the value changes the background color changes to yellow. For further reference check out this fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/Ayan404/xyb764n9/3/

Comment: Make sure your variable **inp** and your color range is the same type. Highly recommend use number type, i mean you need to cast **inp** to number.

Comment: For a proper answer, you need to provide a [mcve], and it should be **within** the question, not as an external link (or both).

Comment: Nice, you should care about type when using JavaScript. To avoid this, you can use **type = "number"** in your input.

Comment: no i can't really do that because those input are coming dynamically from the database

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
inp = $(this).val();
```

with:

```
var inp = $(this).val();
```

Comment: I coded this way during the first time but the issue was there you can check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ayan404/xyb764n9/3/